# iphone automated diagram from ViewController code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uml, diagram

i'm searching a tool that create diagram from an Xcode project. I have tried `OmniGraffle` and `Visual Paradigm` (that seems not work...),and some others tools... 
Seems that all this tool create a diagram that simply draw the #import of all the classes of a xcode project. I need a tool that draw the code flow  inside a class or a ViewController, i need something like : `"ViewDidLoad->ViewWillAppear->ViewDidAppear->ecc...`" . There's a tool for this pourpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is unlikely anything that does what you are wanting to. IDA can give you a dissasembly of your code and visually show logic flows:

https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml

If you learn to use the debugger well you can step through code execution:
 http://lldb.llvm.org/

Answer (score 0):

For exactly what you want I don't think there is any thing.  You could just

```
NSLog(@"entering %s" ,  __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  ) ;
```

on every method.

Then run.  Take the output and using AppleScript have OmniGraffle do it.  I did something like this for a database documentation project many years back.